How to combine iter(), iter::once(), and iter::empty()
The following code works:
let a = [1, 2, 3].iter();
let b = iter::once(&456);

for i in a.chain(b) {
    println!("{}", i);
}

Output:
1
2
3
456

But now, I need to change b (depending on some condition) to be either iter() or iter::once , e.g.
let a = [1, 2, 3].iter();
let b = if some_condition {
    [4, 5, 6].iter()
} else {
    iter::once(&456)
};

for i in a.chain(b) {
    println!("{}", i);
}

But I got:
error[E0308]: `if` and `else` have incompatible types
   |
   |       let b = if some_condition {
   |  _____________-
   | |         [4, 5, 6].iter()
   | |         ---------------- expected because of this
   | |     } else {
   | |         iter::once(&456)
   | |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `Iter<'_, {integer}>`, found `Once<&{integer}>`
   | |     };
   | |_____- `if` and `else` have incompatible types
   |
   = note: expected struct `std::slice::Iter<'_, {integer}>`
              found struct `std::iter::Once<&{integer}>`

What should I do?

Because the types of the two iterators are different, you have to type-erase them behind a common abstraction.
Then the correct behaviour is chosen at run-time (dynamic dispatch).
fn main() {
    for attempt in 0..2 {
        println!("~~~~ attempt={} ~~~~", attempt);
        let a = [1, 2, 3].iter();
        let b: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &i32>> = if attempt == 0 {
            Box::new([4, 5, 6].iter())
        } else {
            Box::new(std::iter::once(&456))
        };
        for i in a.chain(b) {
            println!("{}", i);
        }
    }
}
/*
~~~~ attempt=0 ~~~~
1
2
3
4
5
6
~~~~ attempt=1 ~~~~
1
2
3
456
*/

The previous solution considered the more general case: the two sources of data are very different, but in the end we want to yield &i32.
However, if the problem is really similar to the example in the question, then, we can simply pretend the single value is a slice.
fn main() {
    for attempt in 0..2 {
        println!("~~~~ attempt={} ~~~~", attempt);
        let a = [1, 2, 3].iter();
        let b = if attempt == 0 {
            &[4, 5, 6]
        } else {
            std::slice::from_ref(&456)
        }
        .iter();
        for i in a.chain(b) {
            println!("{}", i);
        }
    }
}
/*
~~~~ attempt=0 ~~~~
1
2
3
4
5
6
~~~~ attempt=1 ~~~~
1
2
3
456
*/


For type erasure you can also use either to avoid allocating, but instead of a once and an array I'd use a slice of length one and a slice of length 3 so there's no type erasure needed at all.
